# Error creating CloudTrail: InvalidCloudWatchLogsLogGroupArnException: Access denied. Check the permissions for your role

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

1. Summarize the problem

My goal is to create an Organizational Trail for an origin account in AWS.

Include details about your goal

The implementation for this trail uses terraform. I plan to use the organization id from an `aws_organizations_organization` data source, `aws_cloudtrail` resource, `aws_iam_policy_document` data source, an `aws_iam_policy` resource, `aws_s3_bucket` resource, `aws_iam_role` resource for cloudwatch logs, and a `aws_cloudwatch_log_group` resource.

The terraform for the organizational trail should be created such that a master trail is created in the origin account which collects from individual trails in slave accounts. This trail should then feed the logs to an s3 bucket in the origin account.

Describe expected and actual results

I expected that the target apply on the specific resources for the origin account should work.

```
terraform apply \
-target=aws_cloudtrail.cloudtrail \
-target=aws_s3_bucket_policy.bucket_policy \
-target=aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_cloudtrail \ 
-target=aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_log_bucket \
-target=aws_iam_role.iam_role_cloudwatch \
-target=aws_iam_policy.iam_policy_cloudtrail_cloudwatch_logs \
-target=aws_cloudwatch_log_group.cloudwatch_log_group
```

Include any error messages

However, I get the following error

```
Error: Error creating CloudTrail: InvalidCloudWatchLogsLogGroupArnException: Access denied. Check the permissions for your role
```

2. Describe what you’ve tried

Show what you’ve tried and tell us what you found (on this site or elsewhere) and why it didn’t meet your needs. You can get better answers when you provide research.

I reviewed the documentation for creating an [Amazon S3 bucket policy for CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/creating-an-organizational-trail-in-the-console.html) and  [Sending events to CloudWatch Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/send-cloudtrail-events-to-cloudwatch-logs.html)

3. Show some code

When appropriate, share the minimum amount of code others need to reproduce your problem.

aws_cloudtrail.cloudtrail

```
resource "aws_cloudtrail" "cloudtrail" {
  name                          = "cloudtrail"
  s3_bucket_name                = aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_cloudtrail.id
  enable_logging                = true
  enable_log_file_validation    = true
  is_multi_region_trail         = true
  include_global_service_events = true
  is_organization_trail         = true
  kms_key_id                    = aws_kms_key.kms_key.arn
  depends_on                    = [aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_cloudtrail]
  cloud_watch_logs_role_arn     = aws_iam_role.iam_role_cloudwatch.arn
  cloud_watch_logs_group_arn    = "${aws_cloudwatch_log_group.cloudwatch_log_group.arn}:*"

  event_selector {
    read_write_type           = "All"
    include_management_events = true
  }
}
```

-target=aws_s3_bucket_policy.bucket_policy \

```
data aws_iam_policy_document s3 {
  version    = "2012-10-17"
  depends_on = [aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_cloudtrail]
  statement {
    sid     = "AclCheck"
    actions = ["s3:GetBucketAcl","s3:*"]
    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"]
    }
    resources = [aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_cloudtrail.arn]
  }

  statement {
    sid     = "AWSConfigBucketDelivery"
    actions = ["s3:PutObject"]
    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["config.amazonaws.com"]
    }
    resources = ["${aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_cloudtrail.arn}/AWSLogs/${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}/*","${aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_cloudtrail.arn}/AWSLogs/${data.aws_organizations_organization.org.id}/*"]
    condition {
      test     = "StringLike"
      variable = "s3:x-amz-acl"

      values = [
        "bucket-owner-full-control"
      ]
    }
  }

  statement {
    sid     = "AWSCloudTrailWrite"
    actions = ["s3:PutObject","s3:*"]
    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"]
    }
    resources = ["${aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_cloudtrail.arn}/AWSLogs/${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}/*","${aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_cloudtrail.arn}/AWSLogs/${data.aws_organizations_organization.org.id}/*"]
    condition {
      test     = "StringLike"
      variable = "s3:x-amz-acl"

      values = [
        "bucket-owner-full-control"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

-target=aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_cloudtrail \

```
resource aws_s3_bucket s3_bucket_cloudtrail {
  bucket        = "${local.name}-cloudtrail"
  acl           = "private"
  force_destroy = true
  # 3.6 Ensure S3 bucket access logging is enabled on the CloudTrail S3 bucket (Automated)
  logging {
    target_bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_log_bucket.id
    target_prefix = "log/"
  }

  server_side_encryption_configuration {
    rule {
      apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
        kms_master_key_id = aws_kms_key.nfcisbenchmark.arn
        sse_algorithm     = "aws:kms"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

-target=aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_log_bucket \

```
resource aws_s3_bucket s3_bucket_log_bucket {
  bucket = "${local.name}-log"
  acl    = "log-delivery-write"
}
```

-target=aws_iam_role.iam_role_cloudwatch \

```
resource aws_iam_role iam_role_cloudwatch  {
  name               = "${local.name}-${terraform.workspace}-cloudwatch"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.cloudtrail_assume_role_policy.json
}
```

```
data aws_iam_policy_document cloudtrail_assume_role_policy {
  statement {
    sid     = "CloudtrailToCloudWatch"
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}
```

-target=aws_iam_policy.iam_policy_cloudtrail_cloudwatch_logs \

```
resource aws_iam_policy iam_policy_cloudtrail_cloudwatch_logs {
  name   = "${local.name}-${terraform.workspace}-cloudtrail-cloudwatch-logs"
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.cloudwatch.json
}
```

```
data aws_iam_policy_document cloudwatch_nfcisbenchmark {
  version = "2012-10-17"
  statement {
    sid       = "AWSCloudTrailCreateLogStream"
    actions   = ["logs:CreateLogStream"]
    resources = ["arn:aws:logs:${data.aws_region.current.name}:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:log-group:CloudTrail/log_group:${aws_cloudwatch_log_group.nfcisbenchmark.name}:log-stream:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}_CloudTrail_${data.aws_region.current.name}*", 
    "arn:aws:logs:${data.aws_region.current.name}:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:log-group:CloudTrail/log_group:${aws_cloudwatch_log_group.cloudwatch_log_group.name}:log-stream:${data.aws_organizations_organization.org.id}"]
  }
  statement {
    sid       = "AWSCloudTrailPutLogEvents"
    actions   = ["logs:PutLogEvents"]
    resources = ["arn:aws:logs:${data.aws_region.current.name}:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:log-group:CloudTrail/log_group:${aws_cloudwatch_log_group.cloudwatch_log_group.name}:log-stream:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}_CloudTrail_${data.aws_region.current.name}*", 
    "arn:aws:logs:${data.aws_region.current.name}:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:log-group:CloudTrail/log_group:${aws_cloudwatch_log_group.cloudwatch_log_group.name}:log-stream:${data.aws_organizations_organization.org.id}"
    ]
  }
}
```

-target=aws_cloudwatch_log_group.cloudwatch_log_group

```
resource aws_cloudwatch_log_group cloudwatch_log_group {
  name              = "${local.name}"
  kms_key_id        = aws_kms_key.cloudwatch_log_group.arn
  retention_in_days = 90

}
```

Comment: What permissions does your user / role have? Are there any SCPs or permission boundaries, etc. in place?

Comment: When I comment out `cloud_watch_logs_role_arn     = aws_iam_role.iam_role_cloudwatch.arn`
  `cloud_watch_logs_group_arn    = "${aws_cloudwatch_log_group.cloudwatch_log_group.arn}:*"` everything works. How do I get perms for my user? I typically use aws sts get-caller-identity to verify that I'm in the right account.

Comment: @EvanGertis were you able to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Your IAM policy for the log group (ie, `aws_iam_policy.iam_policy_cloudtrail_cloudwatch_logs` isn't attached to anything. Instead of a generic role policy, create a [CloudWatch log resource policy](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudwatch_log_resource_policy), like this:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_resource_policy" "cloudtrail_cloudwatch_logs" {
  policy_name     = "${local.name}-${terraform.workspace}-cloudtrail-cloudwatch-logs"
  policy_document = data.aws_iam_policy_document.cloudwatch_nfcisbenchmark.json
}
```

In addition, you'll need to add your role as a principal to the policy, something like this in each statement :

```
principals {
  type        = "AWS"
  identifiers = [aws_iam_role.iam_role_cloudwatch]
}
```